Mistake in Google dev docs for regexSubstitution in declarativeNetRequests?
In the docs, they give an example of a rules.json for redirecting requests:
{
  "id": 1,
  "priority": 1,
  "action": {
    "type": "redirect",
    "redirect": {
      "regexSubstitution": "https://\\1.xyz.com/"
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "regexFilter": "^https://www\\.(abc|def)\\.xyz\\.com/",
    "resourceTypes": [
      "main_frame"
    ]
  }
}

In regexSubstitution": "https://\\1.xyz.com/ shouldn't it instead be https://\\1\\.xyz.com/? As I understand it the \\1 refers to the first capturing group in the regexFilter, and we need another \\ to escape the .

No mistake. The substitution's only special characters are numbered groups \0, \1, \2, and so on.

But the rest of the line has escaped every other period using \\. but they haven't escaped the period right after the \\1.

The escaped characters are in regexFilter, not in regexSubstitution.

Ohh, thanks a lot!
